# watchOS 2: Run code when a user puts on his watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there any way to trigger some code in a WatchApp Extension after a user puts on his watch after not wearing it?

Second best would be to call some code in the iOS companion App after a user puts on his watch.

Answer (score 2):

To make it short, there's currently not such an option in watchOS 2.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful to me. Great how much time you investigated to provide this great and comprehensive answer.